# How do I invoke a method without parameters?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, call, invoke

```
public static void rainbows() {
    Console console = System.console();
    double F = Double.parseDouble(console.readLine("Enter Fahrenheit: "));
    System.out.print("The Degrees in Celsius is: " + ((F - 32) * (5.0/9)));
```

This is the Method I would like to invoke in my Main method. How do I invoke it without parameters?

Comment: Just call rainbows();

Comment: I wonder if you even know how to call method **with** parameter(s). its the same thing, the only difference is _with_ or _without_ parameter

Comment: I was a sophomore in college. This one question now has my account banned....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        rainbows();
    }

    // your method here
}
```